# Are ideals of an sup semilattice always non-empty?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, lattice-orders

I am trying to do an exercise from the book [A Compendium of Continuous Lattices](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Ekeimel/compend.ps.gz).

**Exercise:** Let $L$ be a set with a transitive relation, and let $A,B$ be ideals of $L$.

(i) $A\cap B$ is an ideal of $L$ iff $A\cap B \ne \emptyset$, for $L$ a sup-semilattice.

In the book an ideal is defined as a *directed lower set* without stating that the set should be non-empty, so the emptyset should also be an ideal because it fullfills the definition vacuously. Are there any restrictions if $L$ is a sup semilattice (i.e. a poset in which any finite nonempty subset has a supremum) such that the $\emptyset$ could not be an ideal? Otherweise the exercise makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the first complete paragraph on page $2$, at the definition of the set $L$ being *directed*:

> As the empty subset is included in this definition as a finite subset, $L$ must be nonempty.

In order for $L$ to be directed, **every** finite subset of $L$ must have an upper bound in $L$, and $\varnothing$ is a finite subset of $L$, so $\varnothing$ has some upper bound in $L$, which is therefore non-empty.

Since an ideal is a directed set, it must by definition be non-empty. (That’s also why they have to define $\operatorname{Id}_0L=\operatorname{Id}L\cup\{\varnothing\}$.)

Comment: @GitGud: Yep; thanks. (I bought that book over $30$ years ago, and this may be the first time that I’ve actually used it for something!)

Comment: oh yes, I overlooked this but it stands there cleary!